# How to receive JSON data from this website?

Tags: php, ajax, json, crossdomain-request.js

please help me  to receive josn data from this site, need to make imei check don't know how to get their response. Tried php porxy page, but unsuccessfull

they use this script, but origin don't let me make crossdomain AJAX
Thanks for attention

```
    $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "http://iphoneimei.info/json/unlock/request" , 
    data: {imei: '012651006507772'} ,
    error:  function() { 
            $("#unlock-msg").html('<span class="red"> Error </span>');
            $("#unlock-loading").hide();
            $("#unlock-main-div").fadeOut("fast");
        },
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data.msg);            
    }
,dataType: "json"});
```

Comment: so what does the PHP proxy give you? why was it unsuccessfull?

Comment: use jsonp for crossdomain requests: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: i don't know how to send POST request via file_get_contents() looked in stackoverflow same but have problem with this site. if you can please show me working script to get theire reponce json

Comment: i'd use JSONP but as i know it sends GET request but this site uses POST this is a problem

Comment: _“i don't know how to send POST request via file_get_contents() ”_ – user comments in the manual are often a good source for additional info, so please look through them first next time! http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php#108309

Answer (score 0):

I would try using CURL:

```
$urltopost = "http://iphoneimei.info/json/unlock/request";
$datatopost = array (
    "imei" => "012651006507772",
);
$data_string = json_encode($datatopost);
$ch = curl_init ($urltopost);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);
$returndata = curl_exec ($ch);

print_r($returndata);
```

However, the server keep given empty response. I don't know if the server is available for public use like that. Is a authentication token required ?

Comment: No AUTOINTEFICATION NOT required bro, hovewer thanks for help, got ideas how to handle that anyway?

Comment: The URL returns a 404 response. I've created a fiddle, even the javascript does not work:http://jsfiddle.net/3YNQt/